# Can I reapply for a "restructured" job opening?

Tags: interviewing, job-search

I went through three rounds of interviewing for a position, and was rejected almost 24 hours after the last interview. They said "based on our needs and organizational structures" that they would restructure the position. I assumed that meant they were hiring internally, but I've gotten word that they've actually put up an entirely new listing for the position. I've read the posting - it's slightly different in terms of its responsibilities & pay, but I'm still a great fit. (The previous position had a set end-date and pay, this one doesn't have either restriction.) It's only been a week between the rejection and the reposting - do I reapply? Do I contact the hiring manager about interest in the new position?

Comment: It is difficult to guess if the new role pays more or pays less, the answers will depend on that.

Comment: Does "third round" interview mean "the people who can say 'Yes'?"  I.e. Hiring Manager and/or Technical Competence people?

Comment: @DarkMatter - yes, I met with several members of the department in the process & the people with whom I'd be working closely with the final interview (hiring manager, program manager)

Answer (score 2):

> DarkMatter: Does "third round" interview mean "the people who can say
>   'Yes'?" I.e. Hiring Manager and/or Technical Competence people?
>
> firbolg: yes, I met with several members of the department in the
>   process & the people with whom I'd be working closely with the final
>   interview (hiring manager, program manager)

Reapplying reads like a low percentage play.  The people who can say "yes" have already met you and they didn't say "yes" last time.

**Having said that, do it anyway.**

Low percentage plays sometimes work.  Reapplying is free and maybe their situation has changed.  Try to contact the hiring manager (skipping the first and second round gate keepers if you can is a good thing from your point of view).

Answer (score 1):

Is calling the people who interviewed you to gauge their reaction an option?

Either way just apply and mention it in your cover letter that you already interviewed, you really have nothing to lose.

Answer (score 0):

> do I reapply? Do I contact the hiring manager about interest in the
>   new position?

Yes, you can reapply.

Just apply the same way you did last time. It might make sense to include a reminder about your prior application and interviews in your cover letter.

Comment: Literally the same answer as mine